# Can't load any drivers on Windows 2008 R2, the example project in VS 2019 results in instant BSOD

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build the example project from VS 2019:

[image]

Then I enabled `testsigning` and try to load it in Windows 2008 R2, the Virtual Machine immediately crashed.

When I loaded MEMORY.DMP in WinDBG:

```
EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - {

FAULTING_IP: 
test!__security_init_cookie+2d
fffff880`0d16d119 cc              int     3
```

It's totally weird, the only call to security_init_cookie is from DriverEntry:

[image]

Does anyone know what's happening? I didn't attach a debugger, so there's shouldn't be any 0xCC inserted.

Answer (score 0):

`0xCC` or `int 3` is the breakpoint instruction. Debuggers can dynamically insert `0xCC`, yes, but that does not mean every occurrence of `0xCC` is inserted by the debugger.

In this case, `int 3` is indeed part of the code of `_security_init_cookie`. It means that if you have a security bug and a debugger attached, you'll break into the debugger. If you don't, you have a crash, and for drivers that's an OS crash.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I need to retarget the OS in Driver Settings:

[image]

The driver is now loadable.